# How does Gamora's sword retract?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In *Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 2*, Gamora's metal sword is able to retract back into its handle even though the extended sword was a few feet long and seemingly made of very strong metal.

The sword is called the **Godslayer**, and it has a back story.

**Can someone explain how Gamora's sword works?**

- What is it made of?
- Who manufactured it?
- How does such a seemingly solid metal object retract?

Comment: It's a space sword in a universe where magical stones can literally alter reality.

Comment: But there is often an explanation.

Comment: You see, when it retracts, it collapses into a storage area in the handle.  It was manufactured by a person, company, or facility which produces weapons.  It is made of protons, neutrons, and electrons, often formed into atoms and even molecules!

Comment: It is called the Godslayer, and it has a back story.

Comment: More than just extendible, the blade is also detachable.

Comment: How does Gamora's sword retract? *Very carefully*.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/32454/2235) I asked on Worldbuilding a couple of years back. Not specifically related to the sword you're asking about, but it has a bunch of ideas for how retractable swords might work in general.

Comment: Note that Star-Lord's helmet collapses into a tiny box behind his ear, and Rocket at least has had guns that fold out to become bigger. There seems to be some sort of make-big-things-fold-into-smaller-things technology available in the MCU that is somewhat commonplace.

Comment: I suspect that the sword is made of handwavium.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the retraction is anything special. In Thor: Ragnarok, Thor uses retractable swords in the arena:

Given that a giant wooden fork was a weapon option, I didn't get the impression that these weapons were anything special.

What is special about Gamora's sword is it can ["kill even an Asgardian"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjKg8.jpg) (image via [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/9yd4vz/more_interesting_tidbits_from_the_marvel_studios/)) according to the Marvel Studios Visual Dictionary.

Other than that, we don't know much else about the sword, including what material it's made of. The material doesn't appear to be even [mentioned in the comics](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/godslayer/4055-56963/). We do know that in Guardians of the Galaxy #25 (2010), Gamora mentions that her blade broke on Thanos's skin. In a different comic she is able to [kill Thanos](https://screenrant.com/infinity-war-death-comics-thanos-gamora/) with it, with the help of an infinity stone in the handle.

Answer (score -4):

Nanotechnology is how she does it.

Comment: Can you offer any confirmation or evidence to back this up?