# What are the powers or abilities of Diana's sword?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman, wonder-woman-2017

In *Wonder Woman*, Diana takes "The Godkiller" sword with her on her quest amongst man. The sword is in a tower that contains revered and special weapons and artifacts.

While

> we learn that the sword is not really "The Godkiller",

it was housed amongst other special weapons.

What, if any, special powers or abilities does the sword have?

Answers from the comics are fine if the sword exists there, or is a reference to a weapon there.

Comment: Wait, isn't Godkiller the name of Gamora's sword? Oh, that was [Godslayer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/160763/70236). Both totally original and not cliche at all.

Comment: It's able to fit inside a close-fitting dress without cutting anything off while walking. That seems like a pretty special ability to me.

Comment: It had the special ability of fooling Wonder Woman.

Answer (score 3):

In the movie, Diana is the God Killer, not the the sword.  The sword doesn't even damage Ares the slightest, so clearly not a God Killer.

By the time of Superman vs Batman she is wielding a different sword, so I wonder if the blade had any magical properties to begin with, and if reforged after being destroyed by Ares, would retrained those properties.

In the comics, Wonder Woman never has a sword of her own. In the DC comics, there is a [GodKiller, wielded by Deathstroke](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/God_Killer_(Sword)).

Comment: If I am not wrong, this is not the same sword in Wonder Woman and Batman v. Superman.

Comment: Just checked it. It is indeed a different sword.